# How do I use Storyboard in creating an iOS Titanium module?

Tags: ios, module, storyboard, titanium

Does anyone have any examples?  I've created iOS and Android modules for Titanium but haven't found any examples where people use Storyboard for visuals.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can load nibs in modules using `initWithNibName`, [check this SO answer out.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10567961/874257)

For storyboards specifically, I think that gets complicated since Storyboards define a whole navigation structure. I think you have two options, break down the specific windows in the storyboard into nib files, and then load those as needed, or open up the storyboard itself using code similar to this:

```
// You have to get the resource bundle first 
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryBoards" bundle:resourceBundle];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourViewController"];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I have not tried this out, but I think the key is supplying the correct resource bundle, and then opening from a modal.