# Appcelerator Module - Instantiate UIViewController with .xib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, appcelerator, titanium-modules

I'm having problems instantiating a UIViewController with it's .xib.

My Code looks like this: ( actually, just look here: https://github.com/mrtnbroder/titanium-module-test )

```
- (void)open:(id)args
{
    ENSURE_UI_THREAD(open, args);

    CustomViewController *viewController = [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

    [[TiApp app] showModalController:navigationController animated:YES];
}
```

and my .xib file is named CustomViewController.xib

and looks like this:

[image: TestCamNavigationController.xib]

however, when I build it, my App looks like this:

[image: iPhone Simulator]

why? what's wrong?

Comment: Did you use Storyboard ?

Comment: I've added a Storyboard file once, but then deleted it. Why? Does that matter in any case?

Comment: Yes, if you start project as a Storyboard Template, by default it will look for Storyboard first & set the root view as Storyboard's entry view.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your nib is not in the main bundle. You should first copy all your nibs into a folder into **module_folder**/assets .

Rename that folder something like Titanium.bundle.

So your directory struction will look like **module_folder**/assets/Titanium.bundle

This will make sure your nib gets copied into the module when it gets compiled.

I make a category on NSBundle like this:

```
//Shortcut if you want to name the bundle Titanium you'll be ahead of the game
+ (NSBundle *)titaniumBundle
{
    return [NSBundle titaniumBundleWithName:@"Titanium"];
}

//Bundles are put in a folder called modules inside the application's main bundle
+ (NSBundle *)titaniumBundleWithName:(NSString *)bundleName
{
    //Change this to accommodate the module's id
    static NSString *appId = @"com.companyname.module";
    NSString *bundlePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"modules/%@/%@.bundle", appId, bundleName];
    bundlePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:bundlePath];

    return [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
}
```

Then you're going to include that category in the file you're using and code this up:

```
 CustomViewController *viewController = 
   [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController"
                                          bundle:[NSBundle titaniumBundle]];
```

Then you'll at least be loading the view from the right directory.

Comment: nice catch with the  category :)
i need to emphasis on the fact that the nib file needs to be bundled and not the xib.

Answer (score 0):

are you doing with sotryboard??

if not than check your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in `AppDelegate`

```
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: I don't use a storyboard. Also, I am developing a module for Appcelerator Titanium (https://tinyurl.com/of8cnwm) so I don't have any access to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. You can view the whole project here: https://github.com/mrtnbroder/titanium-module-test

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
  CustomViewController *viewController = 
       [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController"
                                              bundle:nil];
```

suggests you should call your xib file "CusomViewController.xib".

**update**

With your question edit (and your comments) you reveal that you are developing a module for Appcelerator Titanium.

From what I can gather, Titanium does not use Xib files or viewControllers (it uses 'View Proxies' instead). According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480211/building-native-view-using-ios-module-and-using-them-in-titanium), using Xib files in Titanium is a very convoluted process:

> *You need to convert your XIB to a NIB. The easiest way is to add the XIB to a native project, compile the project, and then pull out the NIB. Dump it in the assets for the module, and then reference it from your module code. ... Note that we usually don't use NIBs unless we have something from a third party that forces us to. It's easier just to create the views imperatively rather than declaratively.*

As I only know native, not Titanium, I cannot help you further with this. But I suggest that you follow the Titanium documentation, and don't confuse it with native iOS development.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get what you mean. You suggest calling `initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController.xib"`?

Comment: No. Call initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController" but change the name of the xib file (currently named TestCamNavigationController.xib) to "CusomViewController.xib". OR alternatively... don't change the name of the xib file but change the code to initWithNibName:@"TestCamNavigationController". But that name seems a little misleading as it is a custom view controller's xib, not a navigation controller's xib.

Comment: Doesn't work. Changed the name, but I still get the same screen as shown above. Updated the Code at Github.

Comment: @MartinBroder -see my update. Titanium UI development differs too much from native iOS development for me to be able to help further.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your xxxmodule.m

```
    -(void)startup
    {
        // this method is called when the module is first loaded
        // you *must* call the superclass
        [super startup];

        yourViewController *controller = [[yourViewController alloc] init];
        controller.delegate = self;
[[TiApp app] showModalController: controller animated: YES];

    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but what Delegate Protocol do you mean? And why `init` and not `initWithNibName`?

Comment: yes you can initWithNibName. You have to set delegate for controller in your module. Because your module is linked to your titanium and we need to set delegate for that. Did you try this code? Does it work?

Comment: I tried it. Does not work.
`[ERROR] Script Error Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/mbroder/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/2986965D-2584-4977-9636-ECA29466A48C/TestCam.app> (loaded)' with name 'CustomViewController'`